# Wildfly: partially publish into .ear file

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, publish

I am using Wildfly 10.0 with Eclipse Neon. The publishing shall be done to an compressed .ear file. The setting "Deploy projects as compressed archives" is checked. I have a module with sub-modules that is added to the Wildfly server. The deployment was previously build via Ant from command-line. The purpose of Eclipse would be to re-deploy some projects which I am working on. My current status is that all modules which were previously in the .ear file get deleted in the Eclipse publishing process despite these modules which are situated as sub-module in the server.

Is there any way to restrict this process to only change via publish the needed modules?

Comment: Your question is a bit confuse, please make it clear providing upgrades about what you've done and what you'd like to have. e.g: do you want an Ant task to make all this for you or only to know if there's any shortkey in Eclipse that does it all...

Comment: There are two ways of deploying my application:
1. via ant and command line - works fine!
2. via Eclipse: Here I want to include all projects into my eclipse workspace. But I only want to deploy the projects with changes into the .ear file of wildfly. 

Does this make it clearer?